# Python: Convert nDimensions list to string and vice versa

Tags: python, string, list

My question is probably simple but I don't be able to figure it out.

Consider this code where mylist can have any number of dimension:

```
mylist = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
mylist
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]
```

It's easy to cconvert it to string:

```
myString = str(myList)
myString
>'[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]'
```

But how to easily convert it back to the same list ?
I never get it work in any situation using .join or .split.
I want it work in any case of the list was configured.

thanks

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: I code for a 3D Software call Blender. The python API make possible to save data property with the saved file like float , int , string but not list with multiple dimension. I just figured to save my list has string and retrieve it in some way later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now mylist is a string. (from your code[enter link description here][1])
So now we pass mylist to eval. 
Code Example below :

`mylist=eval('[[2,3,4,5,6,2],[2,3,4,5,6,2]]')`

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: @Saiful Ecellent! do you know how to do the same in an Ansible task ?

Comment: @AhmedHussein, I do ansible. However, I did not use this yet.